# Cost estimation for an e-commerce Web and App development

Tags: price, consulting, web-development, budget

I want to start an e-commerce, but I don’t have web/app developing background. I took several courses to get me started so I can communicate with developers. I need the web to be done by end of Dec, and the app to be done by end of Apr. My plan is to hire a full-stack developer. However, I will also continue my education in full stack development.

Before I ask my questions, here is a brief description of what I need to be built:

1.A web+app with at least 4 pages

a.Front pg + Products (20-30 products that may be changed once every 6 months)

b.Shopping Cart

c.Login + Account info (Store customer data including CC info, use Paypal)

d.About us

2.From my online courses and research, the following tools would be great for this job:

a.Web front end: Bootstrap + Angular

b.App (Android + iOS) front end: Ionic + Cordova

c.Back end: Node or PHP

Here are my questions:

1.I already have a detailed design with clearly defined specs and functionalities of the web and app. What do you think would be a reasonable time in hours to develop 2a, 2b, 2c? Please indicate your yrs of experience if you don’t mind. The answers might vary significantly depending on the person’s experience.

2.Are there better tools than what I mentioned?

3.Are there any particular areas that I need to pay attention to if I hire freelancers?

4.Given the timeline, how many developers do you think are needed for this job?

Thank you very much for your help. Your answers are very important for me. If you need additional information, please feel free to pm me.

Thank you again,

Eric

Comment: If you want just to sell products, why develop such a big project from scratch when you can get something like Prestashop (or similar) that is ready to use and also mobile compatible...

Comment: I voted to close this because it's not possible for *anyone* else to price your work.

Comment: When you say it's not possible, could you elaborate more? I only posted it for 9 hours. Is it because I don't provide enough information?
I did look into Shopify and Prestashop. However, it is difficult to also include an app, and also store customer CC information. That is why I have to build my from scratch. This is not for a mom and pop type of shop. We expect to have several hundred orders per day.

Comment: Well, I **do not** have an understanding of the project, regardless of how much you type - I never will. I don't know the client (you). I don't know your experience level, your overhead, your region, the market rates for your area, etc. There are so many variables that go into calculating pricing that is it practically **never** possible for anyone to just throw out a number for you. The best anyone could do is post what they *think* would be an adequate amount. However for all the reasons I've listed here... they would all be **guesses** and never accurate. This is just a bad question.

Comment: You've essentially posted -- I want to buy land and build a house - the house must have 4 bedrooms, 2 bathroom and be blue.... what do you think it will cost? -- No one can possibly answer that with any sort of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Prices for development as you describe vary considerably form country to country, even within countries, and sometimes even within counties within countries. They vary from developer to developer, agency to agency, and it is impossible to give you a meaningful quote.

Also, any quote provided, in three years time, will not be a valueable answer for any other reader, so it makes no sense to give you a figure.

Accurate quotes take time to do, which is why any Freelancer doing one does so on the basis of actually getting the work.

If you are buying a car, you do not need to take a course in car mechanics or engineering. If you are buying a computer, you do not need to take a course in microchip design.

Your concern over communicating with a developer assumes developers cannot speak about their work to laymen. For freelancers, if this was true, it would not bode well for their career.

As a freelancer that builds these sort of things as my bread and butter, and have done so for over ten years, I can tell you that your 'specs' are the sort of gibberish I see from customers all the time. Our job is to get to the nub of the matter.

My advice would be to forget that you happen to want to learn this stuff for yourself, and go and visit some development agencies or freelancers in your city/town/local area, talk to them about your needs, let them ask the sort of questions that we really need answered, even if at the time you do not recognize the importance of your responses to certain questions. Be open and up front with your budget.

Choose the agency that you feel most comfortable working with, and can offer you a solution within your budget.